# Add attribute to User table in Controller create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, rails-activerecord, crud

I want my logged in user to be able to create a new "forum". When they fill out the information in the form and click submit it will add 'admin' to their user table.

```
def create
@forum = Forum.new(forum)

respond_to do |format|
  if @forum.save
    format.html { redirect_to @forum, notice: 'Forum was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @forum }
    format.json { current_user.update_attribute :admin, true }
  else
    format.html { render action: 'new' }
    format.json { render json: @forum.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
```

end

I thought this would work but when I try it I get

```
ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError
```

Comment: Please share the Forum schema and `forum` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is happening because of `strong_parameter` , you have to pass `permit`  in `forum` method .

Comment: How do I do that? What do I add to the     params.require(:forum).permit(:name)

Comment: please include your `forum` `def`ination/method in question.

Comment: def set_forum
      @forum = Forum.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def forum
      params.require(:forum).permit(:name)
    end

Comment: Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: yes, few more things. the error which i believe is occurred because you haven't whilelisted all attributes which will going to change. Please now include output of  `Forum.new` output and `puts params` .Please put the output in question or some gits instead of pasting here.

Comment: I figured it out. Thanks